# Google maps api multiple marker mongodb pug/jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, express, pug

I'm trying to display map location with my mongodb collection, the problem is just be able to access one data from mongodb, tried to loop from serverside & clientside client to show data but fail. here the code:

**Sample code from *https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893***

```
script(type='text/javascript').
        var locations = [
            ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
            ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
            ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
            ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
            ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.2674807,106.8066466),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent('<h3>' + '#{egstation.loc}'+ '</h3>\n' +
                        '<p>Navigasi</p>');
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
```

**WITHOUT LOOP: *SUCCESS***

**express:**

```
router.get('/', auth.check_login, function(req, res, next) {
    session_store = req.session;
    Egstation.find(function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'EGShare | Energy Sharing Platform',
            session_store:session_store,
            egstation: data
        });
    }).select('name lat lng loc');
});
```

**OUTPUT OF console.log(data):**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b78132c44b37103cc54180"),
    "name" : "egstation 1",
    "lat" : -6.2674807,
    "lng" : 106.8066466,
    "loc" : "Makedonia MakerSpace Jalan Pangeran Antasari No.44 RT.7 RW.7",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bd564b4bf9ea905c53ee72"),
    "name" : "egstation 2",
    "lat" : -5.2345634,
    "lng" : 124.2453456,
    "loc" : "Ngasal"
}
```

**My index.pug**

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.2674807,106.8066466),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng('#{egstation[0].lat}', '#{egstation[0].lng}'),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent('<h3>' + '#{egstation[0].loc}'+ '</h3>\n' +
                    '<p>Navigasi</p>');
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

**LOOP in Clien-side DOESN'T WORK**

```
for (i = 0; i < '#{egstation.length}'; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng('#{egstation[i].lat}', '#{egstation[i].lng}'),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent('<h3>' + '#{egstation[i].loc}'+ '</h3>\n' +
                '<p>Navigasi</p>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

**ERROR OUTPUT**

```
TypeError: /home/mda/WebstormProjects/egsharev/views/index.pug:265
    263|         for (i = 0; i < '#{egstation.length}'; i++) {
    264|             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  > 265|                 position: new google.maps.LatLng('#{egstation[i].lat}', '#{egstation[i].lng}'),
    266|                 map: map
    267|             });
    268|             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

**LOOP in Server-side DOESN'T WORK TOO**

```
router.get('/', auth.check_login, function(req, res, next) {
    session_store = req.session;
    Egstation.find(function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            egstation.name = data[i].name;
            egstation.lat = data[i].lat;
            egstation.lng = data[i].lng;
            egstation.loc = data[i].loc;
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'EGShare | Energy Sharing Platform',
                session_store:session_store,
                egstation: egstation
            });
        }

    }).select('name lat lng loc');
});
```

*Help me, thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to differentiate my server side code and frontend side code.
Jade/PUG will work well to loop HTML code.
But not to loop Javascript variable.
Better your server side code just render view and not pass any data.
And client side will request another data with JSON response that ease to read by JavaScript.

[Updated]
Maybe your problem is same with here : http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/